Cannot Initialize Firebase Project (no available "Default GCP resource location" setting) Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project
I found this thread for the same error however, I don't have the "Default GCP resource location" setting in my project settings. I have created a Cloud Firestore Database with the us-west3 location. I have tried creating new projects from scratch with no luck.
enter image description here
I have reviewed the following docs, tried creating new projects from scratch,  switched to the paid plan from the free plan, all with no luck.
